# Deactivated a plugin with a filter, but it still enqueues JS files

Tags: plugins, filters

I am using a filter to deactivate a plugin programmatically for page requests where it is not needed, but it is still enqueing assets.

I deactivate it as follows:

```
add_filter('option_active_plugins', 'disable_specific_plugin');
function disable_specific_plugin($plugins)
{
    if (!is_singular('whatever') and !is_admin()) {
        $tooltipforgravityforms = array_search('tooltip-for-gravity-forms/tooltip-for-gravity-forms.php', $plugins);
        if (false !== $tooltipforgravityforms){
            unset($plugins[$tooltipforgravityforms]);
        }
    }
    return $plugins;
}
```

I added a wp_die() to make sure that the function is working as expected and where expected, and I confirm it is deactivating the plugin. But how do I avoid the files being enqueued, which is the main goal here (to increase page performance).

The source code reveals:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="gravity-forms-tooltip-css" href="https://whatever.ddev.site/wp-content/plugins/tooltip-for-gravity-forms/public/css/gravity-forms-tooltip-public.css?ver=2.9" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: where did you put the filter? There's no point filtering the option if your filter is added after the plugin has already loaded

Comment: @TomJNowell - Thanks for helping. I put it in the theme functions.php file. Where else should it go to make sure it runs before the plugin has already loaded? I thought that filter would be used by core to load plugins or not. It doesn't really make sense to make a filter available if it's not going to work.

Comment: it can't happen in the theme, or even in a plugin, plugins are loaded before the theme. It would need to happen in an `mu-plugin` drop in file. Note that you can also dequeue assets and that can be done in the theme or a plugin

Comment: @TomJNowell The fun fact is, in mu-plugin, I cannot use is_page() right?

Comment: nope, it's far too early. `is_page` is not available until after plugins have loaded. You would need to figure out if it's a singular page or not via the URL. If the goal is to avoid assets being enqueued by a plugin, the solution is to dequeue those assets, which is something that can be done from the theme or a plugin after it has loaded. Unhooking the action that enqueues them is also an option. Note that you should file a bug report with the plugin authors regardless of wether you find a solution, but conditionally activating the plugin is not the only or best solution to your problem

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for helping, this should be the answer to the question then. I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far too early to use `is_page`.

`is_page` is not available until after plugins have loaded. You would need to figure out if it's a singular page or not via the URL.

If the goal is to avoid assets being enqueued by a plugin, the solution is to dequeue those assets, which is something that can be done from the theme or a plugin after it has loaded, but before `wp_head` is called.

Unhooking the action that enqueues them is also an option. Note that you should file a bug report with the plugin authors regardless of wether you find a solution, but conditionally activating the plugin is not the only or best solution to your problem